# I'm in Volgograd, Russia. Aside from trains, is there another way to get to Astrakhan?

Tags: trains, russia, ferries, astrakhan, volgograd

I'm basically sitting beside the Volga river at present looking at the ferry terminal, and wondering if ferries or buses run instead of a train to Astrakhan - having just spent 34 hours on a train, I'd be interested in another option if reasonable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You really should not use the bus for this trip - if you don't like Russian trains, you'll definitely will not like the buses on our roads.
There are a lot of ferry companies serving this route and I recommend you to visit the [Ferry station](http://maps.google.ru/maps?q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82.%20%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%20@48.700888,44.520060&hl=ru&ie=UTF8&sll=48.702432,44.525485&sspn=0.017447,0.039611&gl=ru&z=16) on Volgograd and choose appropriate ([Volga-tour](http://www.volga-tur.ru/about.html), for example).
Main problem for you is to get the ticket only one-way - all companies generally sell roundtrip.

Comment: Oh I don't MIND Russian trains, they're very interesting.  It's just that if there's another option it could be fun to do something different.

Comment: Many thanks, am at the ferry terminal now, will hunt out Volga-tour.

Comment: Good luck with that, Volga is beauty now. And never use the roads - they are awful between the cities, unfortunately.